# Transit visa required in Malaysia?

Tags: transit, paperwork, transit-visas, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan passport holder travelling from China to Sri Lanka with Air Asia. I have transit in Malaysia for 9 hours and 25 minutes. I need to know if I need a transit visa if I do not leave the airport.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max.
>   transit time of 24 hours, arriving at and
>   departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL)

and

> Visa required, except for Holders of a valid visa issued by
>   Australia, **China (People's Rep.)**, Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea
>   (Rep.), New Zealand or USA to nationals of Sri Lanka residing
>   in country of nationality holding confirmed onward tickets for
>   a max. transit time of 120 hours, arriving at
>   and departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) on Malaysia Airlines
>   (MH) or Air Asia (AK). When transit time is longer than 8
>   hours it is permitted to leave the transit area

So no, you do **not** need a visa.