# Malaysia Transit Visa for Australian PR with Bangladeshi Passport

Tags: transit, malaysia, bangladeshi-citizens

We are traveling from Melbourne, Australia to Cambodia on AirAsia, and have a 15 hour layover in KLI2.

We are Australian Permanent residents and Bangladeshi Passport holders.

We got our Tourist visa for Cambodia. Our layover will be overnight, so we want to stay in a hotel outside the airport. Are we eligible to transit without obtaining visas?

If not, what is the procedure to get the transit visa for Malaysia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transit visa required in Malaysia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106802/transit-visa-required-in-malaysia)

Comment: I'm voting to leave open because the other question is about the situation of _not_ leaving the airport and different citizenship. That said, the other question does contain good related information.

Answer (score 2):

These are the requirements to qualify for the transit without visa for up to 5 days, as shown in Timatic:

> - Nationals of Bangladesh, India, Pakistan and Sri Lanka
>     transiting through Kuala Lumpur (KUL) with a confirmed
>     onward ticket for a flight to a third country on Malaysia
>     Airlines (MH) or Air Asia (AK) within 120 hours. They must:
>
>   - have a residence permit issued by Australia, China
>       (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New
>       Zealand or USA, and
>   - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
>   - have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Passengers in transit for longer than 8 hours are allowed to
>     leave the transit area if:
>
> - returning from or traveling to the country which issued
>     the residence permit, and
> - having a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the
>     arrival date.

You don't need to obtain any visa in this case. Just go directly to immigration at KLIA. Do not go to the visa on arrival counter.